# How to get the list of parameters of the supplied Stored procedure in oracle 11g

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I need a query in oracle 11g to get the list of all parameters, their data-type and their mode(IN or OUT) for a given Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at `ALL_ARGUMENTS` or `USER_ARGUMENTS` Tables.

```
SELECT ARGUMENT_NAME,DATA_TYPE,IN_OUT 
FROM USER_ARGUMENTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = UPPER('ProcedureName');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get a view about the parameters of the procedure, just use

```
 SQL> desc <procedure name>;
```

If you would like to see the code for the procedure, then use (assuming you are logged in as the owner of the procedure)

```
 SQL> SELECT Text FROM User_Source WHERE Name ='PROCEDURENAME' ORDER BY Line;
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following query

```
 select * from user_source where type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

This will give you all the stored procedures stored in your schema. Alternatively, you can also define type as Function or Packages to get required information.